# App Registration via Terrafom: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create app registration via Terraform using az login and not service principal.
I have 2 roles : Application Developer + Groups Administrator

From Azure Portal it works fine but using Terraform it gives an error :

> ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

This is my Terraform code :

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azurerm = {
            source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
            version = ">= 2.90"
        }
        azuread = {
            source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
            version = "= 2.28.1"
        }
    }
    backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name   = ""
        storage_account_name  = ""
        container_name        = ""
        access_key            = ""
    }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = "....."
}

resource "random_uuid" "app_user_impersonation_scope" {}

resource "azuread_application" "app_reg" {
    provider          = azuread
    display_name      = "my_app_registration"
    identifier_uris   = ["api:app-001"]
    owners            = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
    sign_in_audience  = "AzureADMyOrg"

    feature_tags {
        custom_single_sign_on = true
        enterprise = true
    }

    api {
        mapped_claims_enabled          = true
        requested_access_token_version = 2
        oauth2_permission_scope {
            admin_consent_description  = "Allow the application to access app on behalf of the signed-in user."
            admin_consent_display_name = "Access app-001"
            id                         = random_uuid.app_user_impersonation_scope.result
            enabled                    = true
            type                       = "User"
            user_consent_description   = "Allow the application reg to access app on your behalf."
            user_consent_display_name  = "Access app-001"
            value                      = "user_impersonation"
        }
    }

    required_resource_access {
        resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"  # MS Graph app id.
        resource_access {
            id   = "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d" # User.Read id.
            type = "Scope"
        }
    }

    web {
        homepage_url  = "https://app-001.azurewebsites.net"
        logout_url    = "https://app-001.azurewebsites.net/logout"
        redirect_uris = ["https://app-001.azurewebsites.net/account"]

        implicit_grant {
            access_token_issuance_enabled = true
            id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If its problem  with provider .Try creating alias for the azuread provider, and pass the credentials of  application that you have created  by setting the client ID and client secret values,

Comment: Already did but I got the same error (using the applicatino with cloud application adminitrator role) .
When I tried through the AZ CLI it works, but not via Terraform

Answer (score 0):

Your user requires any of these roles:

- [Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator); or
- [Cloud Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#cloud-application-administrator)

[image]
[image]
More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#all-roles

Comment: I tried to use app registration with "Cloud Application Administrator" role, and specifing the creds (client_id, client_secret), I got the same error.

Comment: And I see in the doc that the "Application Developer" role allows to create app registrations.
This is why my admin assign me this role and not Application Administrator.